# openssl version check and upgrade in php-fpm server

Tags: php, openssl, fpm

I have a server where php scripts are served by php-fpm and when I see phpinfo file, openSSL version is - OpenSSL/0.9.8b and if I log into the terminal and see - it is OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018.

I have a script which I run only through terminal. `php box.php` when I run this, which openSSL version would be picked?.

Comment: What keep you from checking that? `phpinfo` can also be run on the command line

Comment: so you mean if I take phpinfo output from the terminal, it is the same SSL version is used

Comment: Yes. Just run and check it

Comment: it is same as I see in phpinfo on webpage. SSL Version => OpenSSL/0.9.8b

Comment: [root@alpctsssswpa65v box]# curl -l https://api.box.com/oauth2/token
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.box.com:80

Comment: So, any more questions open?